# WPF bind to content control's content property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

How can I bind to content control's content property ?

I'v created custom control :

```
      public class CustomControl 
        {
         // Dependency Properties
public int MyProperty
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(0));
         }
```

In ViewModel I created a property of type of this custom control :

```
    public CustomControl CustomControl { get; set; }
```

In view I bind this property to content control :

```
     <ContentControl x:Name="Custom" Content="{Binding CustomControl}"></ContentControl>
```

Now how can I bind to content control's content property?

Comment: I don't get your question, you just _did_ bind to the Content property of the ContentControl. Please note that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel and for your CustomControl property may be helpful if you want to change it and see the changes in your UI.

Comment: @nvoigt I want access view element from viewmodel that's why I a trying doing this

Comment: Your ViewModel should not know anything about the view, including any UI elements. Can you rephrase your question, because you already _did_ what you ask for. You _did_ "bind to the ContentControls Content". Maybe I just misunderstand your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=Custom, Path=Content}" />
```

I'm not sure what effect this will have though. I have a suspicion it will complain about UI elements already having a parent or something similar.

#### Update

If I think I understand your question correctly I don't think you can do what you want using bindings. This is an alternative which adds a callback for when the content is changed so you can set the new content to the property of your VM:

```
class CustomControl : Control
{
    static CustomControl()
    {
        ContentControl.ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, UpdateViewModel));
    }

    private static void UpdateViewModel(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as CustomControl;
        var viewModel = control.DataContext as MyViewModel;
        viewModel.CustomControl = control;
    }
}
```

You'll probably want some error handling in there.

Comment: nvoigt is right, it's very unusual for your VM to know about any UI elements and it's strongly discouraged. Hopefully there is a good reason here.